# A one-sided inverse is two-sided in a group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

The title may not be perfectly worded, but the idea is that in a group, if I want to show that $b = a^{-1}$, I only need to show that $ab = e$. The other side, $ba = e$, almost "comes for free."

I'm trying to understand the precise justification for this. I've read some explanations say this is "uniqueness" of the group inverse, but I'm not sure if this is the case. The foundational result that I have in mind is that if I have any set $S$ with an identity and associative binary operation, and some element $s \in S$ admits a left inverse $\ell$ and a right inverse $r$, one can prove that $\ell = r$. Indeed, we can say that
$$
\ell = \ell \cdot e = \ell \cdot (s \cdot r) = (\ell \cdot s) \cdot r = e \cdot r = r.
$$
So if an element has both a left inverse and a right inverse, they are equal, and we have $s \ell = \ell s = s$ and $s r = r s = s$, so I can write either $\ell = s^{-1}$ or $r = s^{-1}$.

So working back to the example above, I know that $a$ has some inverse, $a^{-1}$. If I establish $ab = e$, then I have that $b$ is a right inverse of $a$. But $a^{-1} a = e$ (and also a right inverse, but I'll ignore that for a moment), so $a^{-1}$ is a left inverse. Taking $b = r$ and $a^{-1} = \ell$, the above result gives $b = a^{-1}$.

My question is: am I using uniqueness to make this assertion?

Comment: You should specify how you define a group; sometimes they are defined so that the identity and the inverses are two-sided. Sometimes they are defined so that the identity is two sided and the inverses are only specified on one side. Sometimes they are defined to have one-sided identities and one-sided inverses (on the same side necessarily), and then you need to *prove* that you get the two-sidedness.

Comment: By the way, it is confusing to use $a^{-1}$ when you have not established the existence of a (two sided) inverse yet, if that is the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniqueness is not necessary. If $ab=e$, then $b=be=bab$. Multiply on the right by $b^{-1}$, the right inverse of $b$. Then

$$\begin{align}
e&=bb^{-1}\\
&=(bab)b^{-1}\\
&=bae\\
&=ba.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You do no use uniqueness and you do not need it: $ab=e\to (ba)b=be=b$. Multiplying by $b^{-1}$ gives $ba=e$.